# Nginx configuration for a static Vue SPA and PHP app

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, vue.js, nginx, vue-router

I know this isn't an ideal setup by any stretch, but I'm hoping someone can help me make this scenario work. Essentially, I have both a:

- Vue SPA app

  - Marketing Front-end
  - Only a few URIs:

    - hxxps://domain.com
    - hxxps://domain.com/#/{*home*|*contact*|*login*}
- Codeigniter (CI) PHP app

  - Main application
  - Centralized router & Laravel-like (index.php?$uri) w/ several URI endpoints:
  - hxxps://domain.com/{*dashboard*|*account*|*etc*}

I'm really trying to avoid embedding the static Vue app within Codeigniter (seems like additional overhead) and avoid a proxy approach since it's static content and doesn't require Node to run.

Here's my attempt so far with the Nginx configuration:

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
  root /var/www;
  index index.php index.html;

  location / {
    # Codeigniter
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?/$request_uri;

    # Vue SPA
    if ($uri ~ '') {
      root /var/www/path_to_spa/dist;
    }
  }
}
```

The asset paths I've successfully hardwired for both apps.

This appears good enough for routing between the Vue and CI apps, but the CI app fails to handle POST and the redirect requests now because I'm getting 404s- probably because of the loose URI check.

Nginx forbids conditional (if) *try_files* statements, so I feel like my hands are pretty tied. Wondering if anyone be able to help with a more elegant solution here :)

Comment: Instead of doing if( $uri ~ '' ), have you tried location = / { 
?

Comment: @PavelLint I tried a location = / and dropped the $uri check (for the SPA) and made the default location / for just the PHP app, but now it only defaults to the PHP app now, unfortunately

Comment: Is this for production? What hosting provider are you using?

Comment: Ok but this config works now except for post-requests? I.e. you get SPA app on `/` and PHP on other routes?

Comment: @PavelLint yeah, the one I have bizarrely seems to load both, just POST requests return 404s.

Comment: @brice I'm doing this in a staging environment that mirrors prod, but hosting with AWS. PHP app worked fine until I started tinkering with the Nginx conf

Comment: If you're hosting with AWS, consider serving the static files of your vue app from S3 instead

Answer (score 0):

If the config you have already works for you fine and only gives errors on POST requests, maybe you could just check if it's POST?

```
server { 
  set $vue 0;

  root /var/www;
  index index.php index.html;

  location / {
     # Codeigniter
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?/$request_uri;

     if( $uri = '' ) {
        set $vue 1;
     }
     if ($request_method = POST ) {
       set $vue 0; 
     }

     #Vue SPA
     if( $vue = 1 ) {
        root /var/www/path_to_spa/dist;
     }
  }
}
```

Untested, but I think you can make it work. Cheers!